# php xpath select div with class "A" only if it has a child with class "a1"

Tags: php, xpath

Given the following html fragment, how can i select all the div's with class `a` or `c` only if they have a child div with class `a1`

Rigth now i have the following xpath query:

`//div[@id='z']/div[@class='a' or @class='c']`

```
<div id="z">
    <div class="a"><!-- Should be  selected -->
        <div class="a1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a"><!-- Should be  selected -->
        <div class="a1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="c"><!-- Should be  selected -->
        <div class="a1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
//div[(@class='a' or @class='c') and div[@class='a1']]
```

**Always avoid using `//` when the structure of the XML is known**. `//` is often very inefficient, because it causes the traversal of the complete subtree whose top element is the context node.

Answer (score 3):

```
/div[@id='z']/div[@class='a' or @class='c'][div[@class='a1']]
```

[live link](http://codepad.org/7WJsu7B7)